# react native run ".\packager\packager.sh" failed

Tags: android, reactjs

run `.\gradlew :Example:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug`

```
:ReactAndroid:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:ReactAndroid:compileLint
...
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'HTC One - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 1080x1920 - 4.2.2' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

then ,run `.\packager\packager.sh` start service.

problem come cross:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'F:\gitProject\local-cli\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:962:3
```

PS:I create 'AwesomeProject' follow the react-native doc works well.